# How to add swagger xml comments per api version with abp?

Tags: c#, swagger, aspnetboilerplate

I found its possible to setup swagger comment with abp framework like normal time when i use swagger without abp,i have try to add “///summary tag” to my Application's api code, but it haven’t appeared at swagger UI page.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write summary/description on class implementation, not on interface.

Related issue: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3285